# fixing a grammar to LR(0)

Tags: parsing

**Question:**

Given the following grammar, fix it to an LR(O) grammar:

```
S -> S' $
S'-> aS'b | T
T -> cT | c
```

**Thoughts**
I've been trying this for quite sometime, using automatic tools for checking my fixed grammars, with no success. Our professor likes asking this kind of questions on test without giving us a methodology for approaching this (except for repeated trying). Is there any method that can be applied to answer these kind of questions? Can anyone show this method can be applied on this example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an automatic procedure, but the basic idea is to *defer decisions*. That is, if at a particular state in the parse, both shift and reduce actions are possible, find a way to defer the reduction.

In the LR(0) parser, you can make a decision based on the token you just shifted, but not on the token you (might be) about to shift. So you need to move decisions to the end of productions, in a manner of speaking.

For example, your language consists of all sentences `{ ancmbn$ | n ≥ 0, m > 0}`. If we restrict that to `n > 0`, then an LR(0) grammar can be constructed by deferring the reduction decision to the point following a `b`:

```
    S -> S' $.
    S' -> U | a S' b.
    U -> a c T.
    T -> b | c T.
```

That grammar is LR(0). In the original grammar, at the itemset including `T -> c .` and `T -> c . T`, both shift and reduce are possible: shift `c` and reduce before `b`. By moving the `b` into the production for `T`, we defer the decision until after the shift: after shifting `b`, a reduction is required; after `c`, the reduction is impossible.

But that forces every sentence to have at least one `b`. It omits sentences for which `n = 0` (that is, the regular language `c*$`). That subset has an LR(0) grammar:

```
    S -> S' $.
    S' -> c | S' c.
```

We can construct the union of these two languages in a straight-forward manner, renaming one of the `S'`s:

```
    S -> S1' $ | S2' $.
    S1' -> U | a S1' b.
    U -> a c T.
    T -> b | c T.
    S2' -> c | S2' c.
```

This grammar is LR(0), but the form in which the end-of-input sentinel `$` has been included seems to be cheating. At least, it violates the rule for augmented grammars, because an augmented grammar's base rule is always `S -> S' $` where `S'` and `$` are symbols not used in the original grammar.

It might seem that we could avoid that technicality by right-factoring:

```
    S -> S' $
    S' -> S1' | S2'
```

Unfortunately, while that grammar is still deterministic, and does recognise exactly the original language, it is not LR(0).

(Many thanks to @templatetypedef for checking the original answer, and identifying a flaw, and also to @Dennis, who observed that `c*` was omitted.)

Comment: Is this a valid rewrite? I can't seem to derive aacbb.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Thanks, I read the grammar too quickly. Fixed my rewrite, I hope.

Comment: @rici, I am afraid this is still isn't enough. In the original grammar, you could derive `c` (`S -> S' -> T -> c`). I didn't manage derive `c` using your suggested LR(0) grammar.

Comment: @Dennis: that's true. In fact, you can't derive anything in`c+`. I don't think there is a good fix for that, and I can't remember what my intention was seven years ago when I wrote this answer. I'm not totally satisfied with today's edit; I think it needs a better explanation of why we usually use augmented grammars for LR parsing. (Only languages with the prefix property are LR(0); adding the `$` token creates a language which satisfies the property. The prefix property is that no sentence is a prefix of another sentence.) Anyway, thanks for the bug report.

Comment: @rici: That's pretty hard to fix something from 7 years ago.. Thank you for for the detailed answer anyway!